# Remote object and stub

Tags: rmi

A serialized copy of the stub is sent over the wire but not a serialized copy of the server.
The stub has all the methods of the remote object .

What difference would it make had a serialized copy of the server been sent instead of a serialized copy of the stub?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What difference would it make had a serialized copy of the server been sent instead of a serialized copy of the stub?

It would cease being Remote Method Invocation completely, and become a mobile agent pattern. Method invocation on the object would be local instead of remote.